# ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng' in python

Tags: python, database-connection, mysql-python

I am getting `ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'` when using MySQL Connector in Python.
My Traceback is as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"DB_Module.py\", line 151, in QueryDatabase
  File \"\\share\app\Modules\mysql\connector\__init__.py\", line 44, in Connect
  File \"\\share\app\Modules\mysql\connector\connection.py\", line 106, in __init__
  File \"\\share\app\Modules\mysql\connector\connection.py\", line 325, in connect
  File \"\\share\app\Modules\mysql\connector\connection.py\", line 288, in _open_connection
  File \"\\share\app\Modules\mysql\connector\network.py\", line 326, in open_connection
  File \"\\sfs\show_time\Showtime_Package\showtime\Modules\mysql\connector\errors.py\", line 160, in __init__
  File \"\\share\app\Modules\mysql\connector\locales\__init__.py\", line 52, in get_client_error
ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'
```

And my Current used SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM systemdetails 
WHERE System_ID = 'System1' LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for the MySql connector to print the actual error string - it needs the eng/client_error file in the "locales" dir.

I personally, just manually created the dir "eng" and copy-paste the file from this link:
http://pydoc.net/Python/mysql-connector-python/1.0.7/mysql.connector.locales.eng.client_error/

```
> mkdir eng
> touch eng/__init__.py
> vi eng/client_error.py
> ... copy-paste, save, and exit.
```

I run the code again, and received:

```
2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

You'll probably get a different error, but hope it helps.

Comment: For me the files are already there, and if I import directly from the interpreter, it seems to import just fine.

Comment: @avatarofhope2 remember that in a single computer(linux/mac) you might have more than one `python3` binaries, i.e: on mac we have `virtualenv` / `/usr/bin` and `homebrew` under the `/opt` - somewhere in these options - the files aren't there - because the error says that it wants to print it - but doesn't know how to translate the error to the language you are in because the dir / file is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Just put this to import the locale when you compile again with pyInstaller or py2exe.

```
from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error
```

They will include the modules needed to fix the error.

Comment: "from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error"

This is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing the latest mysql.connector module to a former version solved the problem. I changed the version from 8.0.30 to 8.0.17.