# Import Error - No localization support for language 'eng'

Tags: python, mysql, exe, pyinstaller, mysql-connector

I know there was a question related to this question. But I could not find what I expected .

[ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893085/importerror-no-localization-support-for-language-eng-in-python)

I am getting the error - `Import Error - No localization support for language 'eng'`

As stated in the other question I do not where to put locales folder, eng folder and the client_error.py file. Because I am converting my python program int an executable using pyinstaller.

So can anyone help me to fix this error.

Comment: Check this http://pydoc.net/mysql-connector-python/2.0.2/ and on the left panel, you can find the directory tree, get inside...you'll find where they are

Comment: I know this thread is a year ago. But did the error has been resolve when you just import ```from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error```? I imported it and right now I am on investigation wether it has been resolve or what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your python file, add this line of code to import the error messages required.

```
from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error
```

pyinstaller will use this information to include the error messages to the compiled executable.