# aws lambda python ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng' in python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using a python code in aws lambda, and just like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077532/import-error-no-localization-support-for-language-eng) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893085/importerror-no-localization-support-for-language-eng-in-python/27168062#27168062?newreg=d93993d3e4d542208929c739184943ac), i'm getting the error when opening a connection with mysql connector.

I already verify that the files **init.py** and client_error.py are inside the folder connector/locales/eng, and my code is zipped correctly.

That's the error i got in logs:

```
[ERROR] ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 31, in main
    connection, cursor = database.connect(host   = HOST,
  File \"/var/task/database.py\", line 7, in connect
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=host,
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/__init__.py\", line 218, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/connection.py\", line 107, in __init__
    self.close()
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/connection.py\", line 319, in close
    self.cmd_quit()
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/connection.py\", line 665, in cmd_quit
    self._socket.send(packet, 0, 0)
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/network.py\", line 166, in send_plain
    raise errors.OperationalError(
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/errors.py\", line 187, in __init__
    self.msg = get_client_error(self.errno)
  File \"/var/task/package/mysql/connector/locales/__init__.py\", line 58, in get_client_error
    raise ImportError(\"No localization support for language '{0}'\".format("
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?