# I am getting ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'. I've seen solutions but I didnt understand them

Tags: python, mysql

I've seen some solutions with that link: [ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893085/importerror-no-localization-support-for-language-eng-in-python) But I couldn't manage to reach neither locales nor download links. Btw the problematic codes are these ones:

`def __del__(self): self.connection.close() print("Db Silindi.")`