# Problem while packaging python code using py2exe

Tags: python, mysql-connector, py2exe

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import mysql.connector as msql
def play():

    # Creating toplevel window under root
    wind2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    wind2.title("Periodic Properties Quiz")
    wind2.geometry('400x350')
    wind2.iconbitmap("periodic-table.ico")
    v = tk.IntVar()

    # Connecting to mySQL database and creating cursor object
    cnx = msql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "manager", database = "GAME")
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
query1 = "INSERT INTO HIGH_SCORE VALUES('{}', {})".format(us_name, score)
cursor.execute(query1)
cnx.commit()
```

I have created a gui program in python, a part of which fetches records from a mysql database. I am using mysql.connector. When I run this part of my code in the exe file, I get the error `Import Error - no localisation support for language 'eng'`. As suggested on various online platforms, I tried `from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error`. But doing so gives another error- `Authentication plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not supported`. If I explicitly pass `auth_plugin='caching_sha2_password'`, even this is reported as not supported.

My code runs fine when just executing the script by its own. All these problems occur with the exe file created using py2exe.

Comment: Could you post a minimally reproducable example of your code with the import causing the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Based on this post, it sounds like your actual problem is the Authentication plugin issue.  The import error was that MySQL couldn't print the Authentication error without the eng locale folder for the error messages.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893085/importerror-no-localization-support-for-language-eng-in-python

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I've posted a part of my code here. Hope it helps you understand my problem

Comment: @nigh_anxiety If I manually copy the eng folder inside locales, the exe doesn't run at all and perhaps the library.zip gets corrupted